# Dining room light comes on when using an outlet

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

I have a free standing pantry with an outlet and a light switch on it.

light switch works just fine. The problem is when I use the outlet I.E. plug the vacuum or anything else into it and power it on, the light that is controlled by the switch comes on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this free standing pantry receiving its power. Is there access to how it is wired from its source to its switch and outlet ?

Comment: What does the dining room light have to do with it ? **Clarification is needed. More info**.

Answer (score 2):

I would alter your thinking.  The light switch and the socket are not "just fine."

Odds are your switch or your socket (or both) somehow have the ground / return wires incorrectly wired.  So either the switch routes the return into the ground when closed or worse.  The plug is likely on the same circuit and completing the circuit for the switch due to the miswiring.  This could be done a number of ways, some which involve the misconnected ground feeding electricity into the plugged in device, returning through the return (or some other odd but similar arrangement).

I'd have an electrician go over the switch, the light, and the socket.  If any of these items were rewired, odds are there was an undetected issue, as they didn't plug something into the socket and test the light in conjunction (and the device seemed to work).